# NDSolveValue taking too long

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation, axisymmetry

I am trying to solve heat diffusion equation on hollow cylinder with constant `DirichletCondition` on inner radius and zero `NeumannCondition` (no conduction) on outer radius. Initial condition is linearly with `r` decreasing temperature. My code:

```
h = 10;
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, 2];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, 4];
cyl = DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1]];
Laplacian[u[t, r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]
ClearAll[r]
ifun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, r, θ, z], t] == 
     Laplacian[u[t, r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, 
       "Cylindrical"] + NeumannValue[0.1, (0 < z < h) && (r > 3.9)], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, r, θ, z] == 50, r < 2.1], 
    u[0.001, r, θ, z] == 50 - ((50 - 10)/(4 - 2))*r}, 
   u, {t, 1, 5}, {r, θ, z} ∈ cyl, Method -> Automatic];
SliceContourPlot3D[
 ifun[4, r, θ, z], {r, θ, z} ∈ cyl, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]
```

The question is why is `NDSolveValue` taking so long.

EDIT:
**How to convince Mathematica to interpret (r,theta,z) as cylindrical (not cartesian) coordinates of a region `cyl`?**

Comment: Hi kular.  On your machine, how long does it take to run?

Comment: I'm running it for 2 hours, still no result.

Comment: @kular You made a typo with `Cylinder[]`. In the cylindrical coordinate it is not cylinder, but region $2\le r\le 2, 0\le \theta \le 2\pi, 0\le z\le h$

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
h = 10;
innerR = 2;
outerR = 4;
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, innerR];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, outerR];
cyl = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1], MaxCellMeasure -> .5];
cyl["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pde = D[u[t, r, θ, z], t] == Laplacian[u[t, r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
    NeumannValue[1/10, (0 < z < h) && (r > 39/10)];

ic = u[1/1000, r, θ, z] == 50 - ((50 - 10)/(4 - 2))*r;

ifun = NDSolveValue[{pde, DirichletCondition[u[t, r, θ, z] == 50, 
    r < 21/10], ic}, u, {t, 1/1000, 5}, {r, θ, z} ∈ cyl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finishes right away.

Comment: There is a typo with `Cylinder[]`. In the cylindrical coordinates it is not cylinder, but `Coboud[]` region - see Tim Laska answer and my also.

Answer (score 4):

In cylindrical space, the annular region would look like a cuboid.  Since there is no $\theta$ dependence in your model, you may as well do an axisymmetric model.  Fortunately, *Mathematica* has a [heat transfer verification manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransferVerificationTests.html) to give a guide on how to setup a verified case, from which, I will shamelessly copy and paste.

```
ClearAll[HeatTransferModel]
HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, \[Rho]_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
  Module[{V, Q, a = k},
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, \[Rho]*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[ FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[ VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (* Note the - sign in the operator *)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]

HeatTransferModelAxisymmetric[T_, {r_, z_}, k_, \[Rho]_, Cp_, 
  Velocity_, Source_] :=
 Module[{V, Q},
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, \[Rho]*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, {r, z}]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  1/r*D[-k*r*D[T, r], r] + D[-k*D[T, z], z] + V - Q]

TimeHeatTransferModel[T_, TimeVar_, X_List, k_, \[Rho]_, Cp_, 
  Velocity_, Source_] := \[Rho]*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
  HeatTransferModel[T, X, k, \[Rho], Cp, Velocity, Source]

TimeHeatTransferModelAxisymmetric[T_, TimeVar_, {r_, z_}, k_, \[Rho]_,
   Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
 \[Rho]*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
  HeatTransferModelAxisymmetric[T, {r, z}, k, \[Rho], Cp, Velocity, 
   Source]
```

Now, we can setup a verified heat equation operator for an axisymmetric case and solve your problem.

```
h = 10;
rmin = 2;
rmax = 4;
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp] = 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == 50, r == rmin];
nv = NeumannValue[0.1, r == rmax];
ic = {u[0, r, z] == 50 - ((50 - 10)/(4 - 2))*r};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{rmin, 0}, {rmax, h}];
tend = 5;
parmop = TimeHeatTransferModelAxisymmetric[u[t, r, z], t, {r, z}, 
   k, \[Rho], Cp, "NoFlow", "NoSource"];
op = parmop /. {k -> 1, \[Rho] -> 1, Cp -> 1};
pde = {op == nv, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp], ic};
ifun = NDSolveValue[pde, 
  u, {t, 0, tend}, {r, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

The solution returns quickly.  We can visualize the solution using the example in the verification manual or from the example on the *Wolfram* website shown [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-axisymmetric-pdes.html).

```
uRange = MinMax[ifun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
legendBar = 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", uRange}, 50, 
   LegendLabel -> Style["[\[Degree]C]", Opacity[0.6`]]];
options = {PlotRange -> uRange, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", uRange}], 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1`], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   Contours -> 30, AspectRatio -> 1,
PlotPoints -> 41, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Temperature Field: u(t,r,z)", 18], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 250};
nframes = 80;
frames = Table[
   Legended[
    ContourPlot[ifun[t, r, z], {r, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
     Evaluate[options]], legendBar], {t, 0, tend, tend/nframes}];
frames = (Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 80] &) /@ frames;
ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
cpfn = ContourPlot[ifun[#, r, z], {r, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
    ColorFunction -> "Temperature"] &;
frames2 = 
  Rasterize[#1, "Image", 
     ImageResolution -> 
      100] & /@ (Show[
       RegionPlot3D[
        rmin^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= rmax^2 && 0 <= z <= h, {x, -rmax, 
         rmax}, {y, -rmax, rmax}, {z, 0, h}, Boxed -> False, 
        Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.2]}, 
        Mesh -> False], 
       Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Gray], 
         GraphicsComplex[{{rmin, 0, 0}, {rmax, 0, 0}, {rmax, 0, 
            h}, {rmin, 0, h}}, {Texture[
            Show[cpfn[#], Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None]], 
           Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
           Polygon[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, 
            VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
                1}}}]}]}], ImageSize -> 200] & /@ 
     Subdivide[0, tend, 80]);
ListAnimate[frames2, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Verification Animation]

[image: New in 10 Animation]

Here is an example of how to make it look more 3D with a [`SliceContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html)

```
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, 2];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, 4];
cyl = RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1];
frames3 = 
  Rasterize@
     SliceContourPlot3D[
      ifun[#, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z], {x, y, z} \[Element] cyl, 
      PlotRange -> uRange, 
      ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", uRange}], 
      ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5`], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
      Contours -> 30, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
      PlotPoints -> 40] & /@ Subdivide[0, tend, 40];
ListAnimate@frames3
```

[image: Slice Plot 3D]

Comment: (+1) But this is actually 2D, not 3D. How it could be solve in a case of 3D?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks!  Yes, it is an axisymmetric 2D model.  The OP question didn't have any $\theta$ dependence, so why not take advantage of symmetry?  I was having difficulty coming up with an advantage to the approach in the OP unless it is to avoid some simple post processing steps.  Your answer revealed something subtle, but important.  Increasing the number of boundary surfaces going from cartesian (4) to cylindrical (6), increases the risk of boundary-boundary artefacts.  Those can be difficult to fix.  You may need to control `PointElement` markers to fix.

Comment: I am wonder that it working in 3D with periodic boundary condition. Usually I solve this problem in cartesian coordinates, then I have no headache with boundary elements and `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[]`.

Answer (score 4):

In cylindrical coordinates region `Cylinder[]` should be transformed into `Cuboid[]`, so effectively we should solve this problem in the region `{r, 2, 4}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, h}` with a periodic boundary condition on $\theta$. Code

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; h = 10; reg = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  2 <= r <= 4 && 0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 Pi && 0 <= z <= h, {r, \[Theta], 
   z}]; 

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg]

mesh["Wireframe"]
pbc = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta] == 0, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi, 0}]];

ifun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], t] - 
     Laplacian[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
      "Cylindrical"] == NeumannValue[0., True], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z] == 50, 
    r < 2.1 && 0 < \[Theta] < 2 Pi], 
   u[1, r, \[Theta], z] == 50 - ((50 - 10)/(4 - 2))*r}, 
  u, {t, 1, 5}, {r, \[Theta], z} \[Element] mesh]

SliceContourPlot3D[
 ifun[4, r, \[Theta], 
  z], "ZStackedPlanes", {r, \[Theta], z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Projection into `{x,y,z}` coordinates:

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
     ifun[4, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y] + Pi, 
      z], "ZStackedPlanes", {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, h}, 
     ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, 
     AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Should there be any $\theta$ dependence?  I would have thought there would be a series of straight lines.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @TimLaska Probably we should increase number of points on $\theta $ or may be it just issues of `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`. But I see that you post a right model.

Comment: I think there is an issue where you have two types nodal boundary conditions on adjacent edges competing for the same corner point.  _Mathematica_ makes a hidden decision about which one takes precedence.  Resolution will help mitigate the issue, but it would be nice to change the precedence so that you could experiment.

Comment: @TimLaska It was issues of `Method->Automatic`. With FEM it looks better.

Comment: Indeed, that looks much better!