# why on some MaxCellMeasure values, FEM gives internal 1/0 error?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, opencascade

V 12.1 on windows 10

When I was answering [NDSolveValue taking too long](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220343/ndsolvevalue-taking-too-long#220343) I noticed the following

When I use some value for `MaxCellMeasure`, then FEM gives 1/0.

Why does this happen? Is it expected? is it internal error? is this a known issue? How is the user supposed to know which `MaxCellMeasure` will cause such errors or not, other than trial and error?

MWE

```
ClearAll[r, t, r, θ, z];
<< NDSolve`FEM`

h = 10;
innerR = 2;
outerR = 4;
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, innerR];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, outerR];
cyl = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1], MaxCellMeasure -> 1];
pde = D[u[t, r, θ, z], t] == Laplacian[u[t, r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
    NeumannValue[1/10, (0 < z < h) && (r > 39/10)];
ic = u[1/1000, r, θ, z] == 50 - ((50 - 10)/(4 - 2))*r;
ifun = NDSolveValue[{pde, DirichletCondition[u[t, r, θ, z] == 50, r < 21/10], ic},
  u, {t, 1/1000, 5}, {r, θ, z} ∈ cyl]
```

Now the same exact thing is repeated as above, but now `MaxCellMeasure -> 1/2` is used instead of `MaxCellMeasure -> 1`. Now these errors went away

Screen shot

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

As Alex properly points out in the comments, in cylindrical coordinates, the proper domain is a cuboid.  So, the problem is more than a meshing issue and was discussed in the answers to previous question indicated in the OP [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220343/ndsolvevalue-taking-too-long/).  If we set up an operator in Cartesian coordinates, the system will solve.  However, one can see that the OpenCascade produces a better solution with default parameters than the poor quality original mesh.

Personally, I prefer the OpenCascade workflow that produces a higher quality mesh with default parameters, but others may prefer different workflows.

## Original Answer with updates

I think it is a mesh quality issue.  If you inspect the mesh that you produced, there are many skewed elements.  Cylindrical objects can be difficult to mesh, especially in 3D.  There might be some obvious setting to improve the quality, but they could blow up the model size.  Alternatively, the [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) seems to produce a higher quality mesh with default settings.  The drawback is that you need to learn a new workflow.

I put together a small workflow so that you can inspect the mesh and see how it compares to an OpenCascade workflow.

```
(* Load Required Packages *)
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
h = 10;
innerR = 2;
outerR = 4;
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, innerR];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, outerR];
cyl = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[cyl2, cyl1], MaxCellMeasure -> 1];
groups = cyl["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
cylgr = cyl[
   "Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors, 
    ViewPoint -> {0.7113990975457255`, -1.1669058777452992`, 
      3.095519665015004`}, 
    ViewVertical -> {-0.27947925602357354`, 0.5162709270999156`, 
      0.8095404099141089`}]];
(* OpenCascade Workflow *)
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[cyl1];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[cyl2];
difference = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[shape2, shape1];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[difference];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
meshgr = mesh[
   "Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors, 
    ViewPoint -> {0.7113990975457255`, -1.1669058777452992`, 
      3.095519665015004`}, 
    ViewVertical -> {-0.27947925602357354`, 0.5162709270999156`, 
      0.8095404099141089`}]];
GraphicsRow[{cylgr, meshgr}, ImageSize -> Large]
q1 = cyl["Quality"];
{Min /@ q1, Mean /@ q1, StandardDeviation /@ q1}
h1 = Histogram[q1, {0, 1, 0.1}];
q2 = mesh["Quality"];
{Min /@ q2, Mean /@ q2, StandardDeviation /@ q2}
h2 = Histogram[q2, {0, 1, 0.1}];
GraphicsRow[{h1, h2}, ImageSize -> Large]
(* Setup PDE system *)
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp] = 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == 50, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == innerR];
nv = NeumannValue[0.1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == outerR];
ic = {u[0, x, y, z] == 50 - ((50 - 10)/(4 - 2))*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]};
tend = 5;
op = Inactive[
      Div][{{-k, 0, 0}, {0, -k, 0}, {0, 0, -k}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Cp*\[Rho]*D[u[t, x, y, z], t] /. {k -> 1, \[Rho] -> 1, Cp -> 1};
pde = {op == nv, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp], ic};
(* Solve and Plot Solutions *)
ifuncyl = NDSolveValue[pde, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y, z} \[Element] cyl];
ifuncascade = 
  NDSolveValue[pde, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
cylMeshPltz = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[
   ifuncyl[4, x, y, z], {z == 0, z == h/2, 
    z == h}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   Contours -> 15, ViewPoint -> {1.348, -2.071, 2.311}, 
   ViewVertical -> {-0.055, 0.106, 0.993}];
cascadeMeshPltz = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[
   ifuncascade[4, x, y, z], {z == 0, z == h/2, 
    z == h}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   Contours -> 15, ViewPoint -> {1.348, -2.071, 2.311}, 
   ViewVertical -> {-0.055, 0.106, 0.993}];
cylMeshPltxyz = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[
   ifuncyl[4, x, y, z], {y == 0}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   Contours -> 15, ViewPoint -> Front];
cascadeMeshPltxyz = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[
   ifuncascade[4, x, y, z], {y == 0}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   Contours -> 15, ViewPoint -> Front];
GraphicsRow[{cylMeshPltz, cascadeMeshPltz}, ImageSize -> Large]
GraphicsRow[{cylMeshPltxyz, cascadeMeshPltxyz}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: mesh comparison]

### Solution Comparison

[image: Solution Comparison]

Comment: Region `Cylinder[]` defined in cartesian coordinates map to `Cuboid` in cylindrical coordinates. So, there is a typo with combination `Laplacian[..., "Cylindrical"]`  and region `cyl`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev.  I agree with you.  I updated my answer correcting the operator for a Cartesian domain.  It solves, but the OpenCascade workflow gives a better solution due to the better mesh quality.  OpenCascade might be a good optional workflow if one is fight mesh quality issues.

Comment: Thank you for update and comparison. It is clear that meshing of cuboid in cylindrical coordinates gives better result as it can be seen from my answer on   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220343/ndsolvevalue-taking-too-long#220343