# Plot time dependent 3D heat equation solution with functions like Plot3D +Manipulate (or Graph3D) but using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting, heat-equation

I have a time dependant heat diffusion equation here and I would like to plot the result of NDSolveValue.

Here is the code I am using :

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r0 = 0.5;
h = 1;

eq1 = D[u[t, r, z], 
    t] - (D[u[t, r, z], r, r] + 1/r*D[u[t, r, z], r] + 
     D[u[t, r, z], z, z]);

ic = {u[0, r, z] == 1};

bc = {u[t, r0, z] == 0, 
   u[t, 1, z] == 0, (D[u[t, r, z], r] /. r -> r0) == 
    0, (D[u[t, r, z], r] /. r -> 1) == 1, u[t, r, 0] == u[t, r, h]};


sol = NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, ic, bc}, 
  u[t, r, z], {t, 0, 10}, {r, r0, 1}, {z, 0, h}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity , MaxStepFraction -> 1/10]

Manipulate[Plot3D[sol[t, r, z], {t, 0, 10}, {r, r0, 1}], {z, 0, 1}]
```

So I end up with something like this :
[image]

The thing is, I would like to have the function plot over a cylinder centered around r=0 instead of plotting the function in a box with 3 orthogonal axis like shown in these answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/need-4d-plot-3d-color-for-function) or [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/need-4d-plot-3d-color-for-function).

Therefore i would like to ask, is it possible to have a plot over a cylinder, maybe with with a color function....Is it possible to plot things using cylindrical coordinates in mathematica ?

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: you do know that the BC and initial conditions are inconsistent?

Comment: My answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220390/61809) shows a couple of ways to take a axisymmetric transient heat transfer problem and display more 3D like.

Comment: @Nasser yes, tbh I do not really know how to get rid of this .... I've tried several types of conditions but to no avail...

Comment: @TimLaska Thank you for the provided answer, I'll be sure to look into it.

Comment: You have likely specified too many boundary conditions.  Note that you have specified both Neumann  (flux) and Dirichlet (value) type boundary conditions at the inner and outer radius.  I am pretty sure you can't do that. You probably want to have one of the boundaries equal to 1 to be consistent with the initial condition and specify a flux on the other.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Do you like picture of the cooling cylinder same as in my answer on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513509/heat-equation-with-newton-cooling/513663#513663 ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I very much do sir. Is there a possibility of having this type of "plot" evolving with respect to time ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I thank you for your answer sir, Is it possible to use the same type of plot, with DensityPlot3D but using a 4 dimentional function where 1 variables is fixed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can modified boundary condition so that it consistent with initial condition. We take low temperature on inside surface of cylinder and warming outside. Then we can prepare 3D frames and animation to visualize process (to make it more visible put `PlotPoints -> 100`):

```
r0 = 0.5;
h = 1;
reg = Rectangle[{.5, 0.}, {1., 1.}]; reg3D = 
 ImplicitRegion[r0^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];
eq1 = D[u[t, r, z], 
    t] - (D[u[t, r, z], r, r] + 1/r*D[u[t, r, z], r] + 
     D[u[t, r, z], z, z]);

ic = u[0, r, z] == 1;

bc = DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == Exp[-5 t], r == r0]; nV = 
 NeumannValue[1, r == 1];


sol = NDSolveValue[{eq1 == nV, ic, bc}, 
   u, {t, 0, 2}, {r, z} \[Element] reg];


frames = Table[
  DensityPlot3D[
   sol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg3D, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, .05, 1, .05}]
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Is it possible to get the same answer but for a 4 dimensional function like ```u[t,r,θ,z]``` instead of  ```u[t,r,z]``` but by defining an intermediary function like this :

```int[t_, r_, z_] := sol[t, r, \[Theta], z == 0.5];
```

And using the function "int" as the argument for DensityPlot3D ?

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Yes, it is. Use `u[t, Sqrt[x^2+y^2], ArcTan[x,y], z]` in this case.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent Yes, in this case we should define `reg=Cuboid[{.5,0.,0.},{1.,2 Pi,1.}]`

Comment: Ok, ty for your answers, I'll have some fun with the code you gave me.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent You are welcome!