# Problem with NDSolveValue : "The function value {$Failed} is not a list of numbers with \ dimensions..."

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I was having fun modifying a code given to me as an answer to a previous problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224912/plot-time-dependent-3d-heat-equation-solution-with-functions-like-plot3d-manipu), courtesy of user Alex Trounev (Thank you again), when I encountered a certain error which I had never seen before.

Here is the aforesaid code :

```
(*parameters*)
r0 = 0.5;
h = 1;
α = 0.8;

(*region definition*)
reg = Cuboid[{.5, 0., 0.}, {1., 2 Pi, 1.}];

reg3D = ImplicitRegion[
   r0^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];

(*equation + conditions*)
eq1 = D[u[t, r, θ, z], 
    t] - (D[u[t, r, θ, z], r, r] + 
     1/r*D[u[t, r, θ, z], r] - 
     1/(α^2 r^2) D[u[t, r, θ, z], θ, θ] + 
     D[u[t, r, θ, z], z, z]);

ic = u[0, r, θ, z] == 1;

bc = DirichletCondition[u[t, r, θ, z] == Exp[-5 t], r == r0];
nV = NeumannValue[1, r == 1];
pbc = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, r, θ, z], θ == 0, 
   TranslationTransform[{0, 2 π*α, 0}]];


(*solution computation*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq1 == nV, ic, bc, pbc}, 
   u, {t, 0, 2}, {r, θ, z} ∈ reg];

(*frames=Table[DensityPlot3D[sol[t,Sqrt[x^2+y^2],ArcTan[x,y],z],{x,y,\
z}∈reg3D,ColorFunction\[Rule]"Rainbow",OpacityFunction\[Rule]\
None,Boxed\[Rule]False,Axes\[Rule]False,PlotRange\[Rule]{0,1.5},\
PlotPoints\[Rule]50,PlotLabel\[Rule]Row[{"t = \
",t}],ColorFunctionScaling\[Rule]False],{t,.05,1,.05}]
ListAnimate[frames]*)
```

When I run the code, after some time, I get greeted with the following error :

`NDSolveValue::nlnum: The function value {$Failed} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {39639} at {t,u[t,r,θ,z],(u^(1,0,0,0))[t,r,θ,z]} = {0.0138161,{<<1>>},{-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,<<15>>,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,-4.66626,<<39589>>}}.`

When I click on the three dots next to the error, I don't find any information on the error like it's usually the case. I then decide to google some answers.
I found some answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/not-a-list-of-numbers-and-cannot-be-used-for-replacing) while also trying to comprehend the error by looking at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21774/problem-using-ndsolve) and finally [that answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

So if I did understand it correctly, such error arises when you use NDSolve (or NDSolveValue) to get a symbolical solution to your equation, but problems come up when you try to numerically evaluate it for plotting purpose, or when trying to get a symbolical result with a function that requires numerical values ?

In any case, I do not really understand why I get such error as my plot part is currently between (* ... *) so it shouldn't matter. As for the rest of the code, I do not really see an error but I am just a beginner so...

Anyway, can a kind fellow enlighten me please ?

Edit 1 : Yes I forgot to tell you that this is quite the time-consuming computation...sorry.

Comment: I got tired of waiting for it to finish....sorry.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I reproduced the error after nearly an hour on my six-processor computer.  The computation consumed nearly every available cycle.  It produce an `InterpolatingFunction` over `{t, 0, 0.0138}`, which appears to go unstable by `t = 5 10^-4`

Comment: There appears to be a sign error in `eq1`.  `- 1/(\[Alpha]^2 r^2) D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta], \[Theta]]` should be `1/(\[Alpha]^2 r^2) D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta], \[Theta]]`.  Correct it, and the computation runs correctly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's alright, don't bother, ty nonetheless.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, changing the " - " into a "+" fixes the issue...but why does it fix the issue though ? That I'd like to understand.

Comment: Regarding the sign error.  Diffusion coefficients should be intrinsically positive.  What is the physical meaning of a negative diffusion coefficient?

Comment: @TimLaska might just be an error on my end, I need to thoroughly check my calculations on my notepad.

Comment: @bbgodfrey since you managed to run the whole thing, does it show a half cylinder to you as well ?

Comment: The sign error in `eq1` caused the computation to be violently unstable., which apparently led to an internal failure in `NDSolve`.  Fixing the error allowed the computation to run smoothly, producing the desired animation.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Although the ultimate cause of the error cited in the question was violent growth of the solution due to an error in the PDE, it seems to me that `$Failed` should have been trapped inside of `NDSolve` instead of being allowed to leak out.  I would consider this a (minor) bug.  What do you think?

Comment: @bbgodfrey  I guess it's a bug. I haven't looked into it, but `$Failed` normally is caught

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness, I summarize my comments here.  The computation for `eq1`, as posted in the question, is violently numerically unstable, due to a sign error.  The enormous resulting growth of the solution apparently caused an internal error in `NDSolve`, and `$Failed` leaked out.  I emphasize, though, that this is a symptom, not the root cause of the failure of the computation.  Correcting `eq1` to

```
eq1 = D[u[t, r, θ, z], t] - (D[u[t, r, θ, z], r, r] + 1/r*D[u[t, r, θ, z], r] + 
           1/(α^2 r^2) D[u[t, r, θ, z], θ, θ] + D[u[t, r, θ, z], z, z])
```

allows the computation to proceed smoothly. To produce the animated plot requested in the question, as opposed to only half of it, replace `ArcTan[x, y]` by `Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2 Pi]` in the final code of the question.  (Only every other frame is plotted to reduce the size of the graphic.  Alternatives are discussed [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2370/1063).)

[image]

Comment: so you do get a half cylinder as well ? That's weird....

Comment: well in any case, thx.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent  I thought you wanted a half cylinder.  To get the whole cylinder, use `Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2 Pi]`.  The problem with your original code is that `ArcTan[x, y]` returns values in the range `{-Pi, Pi}`, and the negative values are outside `reg` and were not computed by `NDSolve`.  I can change my answer accordingly, if you wish.  Let me know.

Comment: @ConfuzzledStudent  Alternatively, use `reg = Cuboid[{.5, -Pi, 0}, {1., Pi, 1}]`.

Comment: If I was just in the middle of checking the ArcTan documentary, your comment came right on time. 
If all I need is to replace ```ArcTan[x, y]``` with ```Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2 Pi]``` then don't bother editing your answer. The computation does take a lot of time and memory. 
Thank you for the additional information.

Comment: I'll try both methods and will get back to you after the computation ends (in 30 mins )

Comment: It works great, thank you very much.